# Application with multiple executables appears signed but triggers firewall warning

Tags: macos, qt, firewall, code-signing, codesign

I'm working on a QT app for OS X that uses multiple executables. We sign the .app by signing each executable within the .app, then signing the whole .app with the "-f" option. This is the procedure Apple recommended when we contacted them.

However, each time our app starts, the user is prompted with a warning that our application wants to connect to the internet. This warning is repeated every time the application is restarted, even if the user chooses to grant it access.

Any suggestions for where our process could be going wrong would be useful. For what it's worth, all executables and the .app itself have valid signatures according to codesign.

Comment: I know this is 5 years ago, but did you ever solve it?