# How to code sign macOS binary to stop firewall permissions requests?

Tags: macos, firewall, code-signing, macos-sierra, xattr

Bowtie app is here: http://bowtieapp.com. The binary but not the source is available.

It has the problem on `macOS Sierra 10.12.5 Beta` that an active firewall causes it to request firewall permissions on every boot. I suspect this can only be resolved via codesigning.

[image: Firewall permissions request]

There is an old fix which no longer seems to work:
https://ivadrenaline.wordpress.com/2015/07/07/do-you-want-the-application-to-accept-incoming-network-connections/

You can sign the frameworks, but then when you sign the whole app you get:

```
/Applications/Bowtie.app/: resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed
```

Googling that error leads to: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1940/_index.html

But while running `xattr -cr` on the app causes the signing to proceed without error, it still does not prevent the firewall dialog permissions request from appearing.

I have also tried `deep` versions of the signing process which did not work.

I think Bowtie has the app itself and a helper application, so it may have more than one executable, and be related to this item: [Application with multiple executables appears signed but triggers firewall warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164192)
Also:
[Why is OSX continually asking for firewall permission for my app which is signed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36656531)
This promising answer also did not work:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40067738/365478

What is the fix for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually adding the application to the firewall exclusions list via the macOS System Preferences UI worked. The `.app` was fine, it wasn't necessary to find the executable. I didn't isolate these changes, so it may also be necessary to codesign the app with the failing methods and/or to manually set firewall exclusions via the terminal, as another answer on the following thread suggests.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10011819/365478

If someone shows how to codesign it properly I'll remark that best answer.